# Why does it show an Attribute Error In Anaconda Jupyter?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdT1C.png)

I'm using Anaconda and running into this error as I would press the run button. Is there something that I'm missing to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post code as text inside a code block.

Comment: Thank you, @TedKleinBergman I'm new around here and I was wondering on how you can do that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`d.labelI()` should be `d.label()`

schemdraw does not have a function called `labelI()`

Comment: Hey there so I changed it with your suggestion and it's still the same problem.

Comment: @AldousKentAlemania did you change all instances of labelI()? in which case the error message would go to the second time that you used that function. Is the error message still the same when you remove all instances of labelI()?